# How do I make a property private in a Laravel Eloquent Model?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Seems almost too obvious, but how do I make a class property private:

```
class User extends Model
{
   private $name; // or protected

}

$user = new User();
$user->name = "Mrs. Miggins";     // <- I want this to generate an error
echo $user->name; // Mrs. Miggins, (this too)
```

This is Laravel 5.1

Comment: You should know: a property of a Laravel model, which used in your example, is not a physical property. It is just a **Model attribute**, only made usable by Laravel Eloquent as a property. These attributes are defined in the Model property called *attributes*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to override `__get(){}` and `__set(){}` magic methods, so it will be something like that:

```
class User extends Model
{
  protected $privateProperties = ['name'];

  public function __get($varName) {
      $this->isPrivate($varName);

      return parent::__get($varName);
  }

  public function __set($varName, $value) {
      $this->isPrivate($varName);

      return parent::__set($varName, $value);
  }

  protected function isPrivate($varName) {
      if (in_array($varName, $this->privateProperties)) {
          throw new \Exception('The ' . $varName. ' property is private');
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice one. I actually turned this methods into a **Trait**, so you can implement this in any needed Model. Could be a nice option too.

Comment: Yes, it would be pretty handy, wanted to write about the `trait` just a second ago :)

Comment: I added a related question here regarding setters and getters:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40337400/adding-setters-and-getters-to-laravel-model

Comment: This doesn't just stop properties being set by code outside the class, it also stops code _inside_ the class setting it, so you could argue it's a misuse of the term 'Private' in OOP. These properties are super private or maybe "Unsettable" would be a more appropriate term.

Comment: You may use `setAttribute()` and `getAttribute()` native eloquent methods for that.