# Adding Setters and Getters to Laravel Model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

If I want an Eloquent Model class to have setters and getters for the sake of implementing an interface does the following approach make sense or is there a 'laravel' approach to the problem

```
class MyClass extends Model implements someContract
{

  public function setFoo($value) {
      parent::__set('foo', $value);
      return $this;
  }

  public function getFoo() {
      return parent::__get('foo');
  }
}
```

Comment: @Doom5 so you can chain methods.  If a setter doesnt return the parent, this cant be done. Always return the object on a setter.

Comment: @DevDonkey Comments like ^^, I wish I could favorite.

Comment: Ah, yes of course. But @Gazzer is using php's `__set()` magic method internally which doesn't really return anything.

Comment: Laravel style is not nice to me since no IDE recognizes the attributes of the models. I want it to be autocompleted and obvious. It is really cumbersome to look at the migration or db table to figure out which attributes the model has.

Comment: @aod you can work that problem around by adding `@property` annotations above your class definition: http://docs.phpdoc.org/references/phpdoc/tags/property.html.

Answer (score 38):

You are probably looking for [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) (getters) and [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) (setters).

Example of an accessor (getter) in Laravel:

```
public function getFirstNameAttribute($value)
{
    return ucfirst($value);
}
```

Example of a mutator (setter) in Laravel:

```
public function setFirstNameAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['first_name'] = strtolower($value);
}
```

Comment: This method naming convention seems more appropriate when setting an attribute via a magic method such as `$myClass-> first_name = 'BOB';` being set as 'bob' and returned as 'Bob' rather than when we `implement` a contract.

Comment: Hi Alexey, do you know maybe how to create a universal getter in laravel....so that gets all attributes Capitalised? I will make a new question on SO if you know this and post the link here so you can answer it...Just say yes or no - here.

Comment: Could you also add an example of how one would invoke these?

Comment: Are you trying to change value before saving to DB (use  [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator)) or get an altered/modified value (use [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators))?

Answer (score 11):

For new laravel you can do this in model :

```
/**
* Interact with the user's first name.
*
* @param  string  $value
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute
*/
protected function firstName(): Attribute
{
    return Attribute::make(
       get: fn ($value) => ucfirst($value),
       set: fn ($value) => strtolower($value),
    );
}
```

Wanna know more? see at : (same implementation)

- https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator
- https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator
- https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator